# Ruby: Force open-uri to return IPv4 address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-uri

In our Rails app, we have a controller action that opens an external URL, and returns it as JSON for our front end to consume.

Today, I got the following error:

`Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT: Address family not supported by protocol - socket(2)`

Our devops suggested that this would be the error if the address returned an IPv6 response as well as an IPv4 response. We don't support IPv6, so that could explain it.

Here's the method that fires off the request:

```
def medline_response
  open("http://apps.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/services/mpconnect_service.cfm?mainSearchCriteria.v.cs=#{codesys}&mainSearchCriteria.v.c=#{code}")
end
```

And indeed, the response from that server's host:

```
$ host apps.nlm.nih.gov
apps.nlm.nih.gov is an alias for apps.wip.nlm.nih.gov.
apps.wip.nlm.nih.gov has address 130.14.16.117
apps.wip.nlm.nih.gov has IPv6 address 2607:f220:41e:1016::117
```

The [docs for open-uri](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) don't say anything about IP version. Is there an argument you can pass into the `open` method that forces it to read IPv4, or another way to deal with this?

### Edit

When I try to open google from the console, I get this:

```
[18] pry(main)> require 'open-uri'
=> false
[19] pry(main)> open 'http://google.com'   
=> #<File:/var/folders/hq/7_rgkt4565q728y91dtqzs2r2wxb1y/T/open-uri20130913-50258-1af4zhv>
```

So it doesn't look like the IPv6 address is an issue there.

### Edit 2

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
```

OS X 10.7.5

### Edit 3

It's everyone's favorite kind of error: an intermittent one. Here's what happens when I call read on the `open-uri` object. I get this same output locally and all 3 of our app servers.

```
[22] pry(main)> open("http://apps.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/services/mpconnect_service.cfm?mainSearchCriteria.v.cs=2.16.840.1.113883.6.103&mainSearchCriteria.v.c=238.4").read
=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<feed xml:base=\"http://apps.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/services/\" xml:lang=\"en\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" xmlns:v3=\"urn:hl7-org:v3\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><title type=\"text\">MedlinePlus Connect</title><subtitle type=\"text\">MedlinePlus Connect results for ICD-9-CM 238.4</subtitle><author><name>U.S. National Library of Medicine</name><uri>http://www.nlm.nih.gov</uri></author><updated type=\"text\">2013-09-13T12:09:48Z</updated><category scheme=\"REDS_MT010001UV\" term=\"MATCHED\"><v3:mainSearchCriteria classCode=\"OBS\" moodCode=\"DEF\" xmlns:v3=\"urn:hl7-org:v3\"><v3:code code=\"KSUBJ\" codeSystem=\"2.16.840.1.113883.5.4\" xmlns:v3=\"urn:hl7-org:v3\"/><v3:value code=\"238.4\" codeSystem=\"2.16.840.1.113883.6.103\" displayName=\"\" xmlns:v3=\"urn:hl7-org:v3\"/></v3:mainSearchCriteria><v3:informationRecipient typeCode=\"IRCP\" xmlns:v3=\"urn:hl7-org:v3\"><v3:patient classCode=\"PAT\" xmlns:v3=\"urn:hl7-org:v3\"/></v3:informationRecipient></category><id></id><entry><title>Bone Marrow Diseases</title><link href=\"http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/bonemarrowdiseases.html\" rel=\"alternate\"/><id>tag: nlm.nih.gov, 2013-13-09:/medlineplus/bonemarrowdiseases.html</id><updated>2013-09-13T12:09:48Z</updated><summary type=\"html\">&lt;p&gt;Bone marrow is the spongy tissue inside some of your bones, such as your hip and thigh bones. It contains immature cells, called stem cells. The stem cells can develop into the red blood cells that carry oxygen through your body, the white blood cells that fight infections, and the platelets that help with blood clotting. &lt;/p&gt;&#xd;&#xd;&lt;p&gt;If you have a bone marrow disease, there are problems with the stem cells or how they develop. &lt;a href=\"http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/leukemia.html\"&gt;Leukemia&lt;/a&gt; is a cancer in which the bone marrow produces abnormal white blood cells. With &lt;a href=\"http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/aplasticanemia.html\"&gt;aplastic anemia&lt;/a&gt;, the bone marrow doesn't make red blood cells. Other diseases, such as &lt;a href=\"http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/lymphoma.html\"&gt;lymphoma&lt;/a&gt;, can spread into the bone marrow and affect the production of blood cells.  Other causes of bone marrow disorders include your genetic makeup and environmental factors.&lt;/p&gt; &#xd;&#xd;&lt;p&gt;Symptoms of bone marrow diseases vary. Treatments depend on the disorder and how severe it is. They might involve medicines, blood transfusions or a &lt;a href=\"http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/bonemarrowtransplantation.html\"&gt;bone marrow transplant&lt;/a&gt;. &lt;/p&gt;&#xd; &lt;p class=\"NLMrelatedLinks\"&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003658.htm\"&gt;Bone marrow aspiration&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003934.htm\"&gt;Bone marrow biopsy&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003682.htm\"&gt;Bone marrow culture&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003009.htm\"&gt;Bone marrow transplant&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/patientinstructions/000010.htm\"&gt;Bone marrow transplant - discharge&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/000589.htm\"&gt;Polycythemia vera&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/000531.htm\"&gt;Primary myelofibrosis&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</summary></entry></feed>  \n\n"
```

That is, it returns the `HTML` as a string, like you'd expect.

Comment: What happens if you do it with google.com? It's got an IPv6 address too. (I get the same thing as you when I do `host apps.nlm.nih.gov`)

Comment: I don't believe the problem is OpenURI or IPv6, because, if they were the problem pair we'd have heard about it a while back. OpenURI reads from the stream returned by the host handling that URI, and OpenURI returns a file-handle to a StreamIO or a file where it spooled the content. Try `read` on the `open` you do on MedLine. Also, what Ruby, OpenURI and OS are you using?

Comment: See edits. I've added that info. OpenURI is part of the Ruby core, so it'd be the same version, right?

Comment: If it's intermittent and your code runs on only one host, I'd point at the network somewhere. If you're running on multiple machines then it's possible there's a different configuration underneath one of those copies of the code. Or it's the network.

Comment: I've tried calling `open`, passing that URI and calling `read` on it from each of our app servers, and it returned that HTML. Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Not sure that this matters but there is a huge issue with this since the adoption of `ipv6` was due to the fact `ipv4` was reaching maximum capacity. Thus there are far more ~(79 228 162 514 264 337 593 543 950 33) IPv6 addresses available. What happens when you hit a situation where there is no resolvable `ipv4` anymore?

Comment: You may to use `Socket.getaddrinfo( 'apps.nlm.nih.gov', 'http', :INET)[0][3]` to get IPv4 addr. And then replace _'apps.nlm.nih.gov'._ As here `open (http://130.14.16.117/medlineplus/serv...)` or with port `open (http://130.14.16.117:80/medlineplus/serv...)` May be. [Socket.getaddrinfo](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-c-getaddrinfo)

Comment: If it's intermittent error, maybe you could catch `Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT:` and request the URL again?

Comment: can you disable IPv6 on the host? I had a similar issue with SSH trying to use IPV6 by default (hosts had IPv6 DNS entries, but no valid route) and removing IPv6 from the system forced everything to IPv4 and it all started working again.

Comment: What ruby version?  If you google for the error you got, there is some info from other people encountering similar problems, including this bug report, which if I'm reading it right was acknowledged as a bug in ruby, but I'm not clear on when/if it's been fixed. https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9477

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need newer ruby, see [ruby bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9477)

You can "force" open-uri to use ip eg:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'socket'

url = "google.com"
ip = IPSocket::getaddress(url)

open("http://#{url}") do |f|
  puts "i'm using url #{url} #{f.base_uri}"
end
open("http://#{ip}") do |f|
  puts "i'm using ip #{ip} #{f.base_uri}"
end
```

Comment: That open("http://#{ip}") is useless if there are multiple domains on that IP, which is pretty common nowadays. In such case, you would need to use full Net::HTTP instead of simple open-uri.